# md5 hash not coming out right

Tags: python, hash

I have a file that has a trailer record containing a md5 hash.  If I do

```
tail -1 MenuMix_353463_20180720140023_22003.csv TRL 8670e09c7dfcd5fc4d6c4fc8cb2048be
sed \$d MenuMix_353463_20180720140023_22003.csv | md5sum 8670e09c7dfcd5fc4d6c4fc8cb2048be  -
```

but when I write my python code I get different values.  My python code does the following:

```
data = ''
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))
for line in reader:
    lineArray = str(line[0]).split('\t')
    if lineArray[0] == 'TRL':
        #check the file hash
        hashObject = str(hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest())
        print ('md5 hash: ' + hashObject)
    else:
        data += line[0]
```

Doing this my calculated md5 hash does not match the hash on the trailer

Comment: Given it's 2018 and MD5 is a joke of a hash are you sure you want to use MD5? Check that you're not doing CRLF to LF conversion by accident.

Comment: sample of input? using csv probably changes the line.

Answer (score 0):

The mention about the csv changing the lines was correct.  I changed to not use csv and now my hash calculation works properly.  Thank you for that trigger - it helped me solve my problem.